# Hyper-V and physical switch trunk port SPAN/mirroring

Tags: html, hyper-v, mirroring

I'm new to the Hyper-V and trying to setup a lab. Here is my setup:

- Cisco switch with a SPAN port (configured to mirror in/out, replicate the encapsulation, source port for the span is a trunk). I verified that I see all packets on the SPAN port
- Server with Hyper-V VM that has two NICs. One is for general connectivity, the other is configured as a mirror destination. Vlan identification is disabled. Mapped to a virtual switch
- Virtual switch is mapped to a dedicated server port connected to the Cisco SPAN port. OS sharing is allowed. VLAN identification is disabled. NDIS capture is enabled but NDIF also lists an errors in the window: *"The Selected Extension is not operating correctly.  Check the event logs for further information. If this is a non-Microsoft Extention, contact the vendor for further troubleshooting steps."*
- Server NIC is configured as a Hyper-V source as explained here: https://cloudbase.it/hyper-v-promiscuous-mode/
- I can only see traffic from the server on the VM port. Nothing from the SPAN.

**Is it even possible to setup what I'm trying to achieve? If so, am I missing something?**

Thank you very much

VM NIC:

[image: VM NIC 1]
[image: VM NIC 2]
VSwitch:

[image: VSwitch1]
[image: VSwitch2]

Comment: Hi Maria, this may be a better question to ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) instead, since it appears to be about server management.

Comment: Thanks. Trying that too